# How to write tests for django form views?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Django v1.10

FormView code:

```
class PasswordResetConfirmView(FormView):
    template_name = "dashboard/account/reset_password_form.html"
    success_url = '/dashboard/'
    form_class = SetPasswordForm

    def authenticate_password_token(self, request, uidb64=None, token=None, encodedtimestring=None):
        try:
            uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
            timestring = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(encodedtimestring))
            timestamp = timeparse(timestring)
            timediff = timezone.now() - timestamp
        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            user = None
            timediff = None

        if timediff is None or timediff.days < 0 or timediff.days > PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS:
            messages.error(request, _(
                'The reset password link is no longer valid.'))
            return None

        if user is None or not default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
            messages.error(request, _('The reset password link is not valid.'))
            return None

        return user

    def get(self, request, uidb64=None, token=None, encodedtimestring=None, *arg, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        assert uidb64 is not None and token is not None and encodedtimestring is not None

        user = self.authenticate_password_token(
            request, uidb64, token, encodedtimestring)
        if user is None:
            return redirect(reverse('dashboard-login'))

        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def post(self, request, uidb64=None, token=None, encodedtimestring=None, *arg, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        assert uidb64 is not None and token is not None and encodedtimestring is not None

        user = self.authenticate_password_token(
            request, uidb64, token, encodedtimestring)
        if user is None:
            return redirect(reverse('dashboard-login'))

        if not form.is_valid():
            return self.form_invalid(form)

        new_password = form.cleaned_data['new_password2']
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                user.auth_token.delete()
                Token.objects.create(user=user)
                user.set_password(new_password)
                user.save()
        except:
            messages.error(request, _('Password reset was unsuccessful.'))
            return redirect(reverse('dashboard-login'))

        messages.success(request, _('Password has been reset.'))
        return redirect(reverse('dashboard-login'))
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?i)recover/password/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/(?P<token>.+)/(?P<encodedtimestring>.+)/$',
    views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='reset-password-confirm'),
```

testclass parent:

```
class BaseApiTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        superuser = User.objects.create_superuser(
            'test', 'test@api.com', 'testpassword')
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = superuser
        self.client.login(username=superuser.username, password='testpassword')
```

My attempt at writing the test case:

```
class ResetPasswordEmailTest(BaseApiTest):

    def test_password_reset_form(self):
        """
        Ensure that the authenticate token works
        """
        self.client.logout()
        token = default_token_generator.make_token(self.user)
        uidb64 = force_bytes(self.user.id)
        timenow = force_bytes(timezone.now())
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse('reset-password-confirm',
                    args=[urlsafe_base64_encode(uidb64), token,
                          urlsafe_base64_encode(timenow)]))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Error message that I got:

```
tests/password_tests.py", line 129, in test_password_reset_form
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
AssertionError: 302 != 200
```

Am not sure how to write a test class to test all 3 methods of the formview. My attempt was just to test the `get` method

UPDATE:

The real reason for the failure has nothing to do with the user login but somehow the `check_token` method inherent in the `PasswordTokenGenerator` was failing my tests.

And as I do more research, I think it would be better that I upgrade Django v1.10 to v1.11 where I need to rewrite this whole thing which may end up invalidating the need for this question.

Comment: Hey, @KimStacks I was wondering, did any of this answers helped you?

Comment: Hi @JohnMoutafis sorry been busy with other tasks, so haven't gotten around to testing the answers. Will do it over the weekend.

Comment: @JohnMoutafis

The real reason for the failure has nothing to do with the user login but somehow the check_token method inherent in the PasswordTokenGenerator was failing my tests.

And as I do more research, I think it would be better that I upgrade Django v1.10 to v1.11 where I need to rewrite this whole thing which may end up invalidating the need for this question.

Comment: What do you mean by `check_token` method fails? What is the error @KimStacks ?

Answer (score 3):

Your *get* method of `PasswordResetConfirmView` is responding with 2 different responses.

**Redirect**

When user is None it is responding with a Redirect URI

```
if user is None:
   return redirect(reverse('dashboard-login'))
```

> So in that case the status code of response will be [**`HTTP 302`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) means
>   that you are redirected to some other URL.

**Render to response**

When there is user, then the information returned with the response is the method used in the request.

```
return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

> So in that case the status code of response will be **[`HTTP 200`](https://httpstatuses.com/200)** means
>   the request has succeeded.

---

### Solution:

In order to make your test case pass you can use [**`assertRedirects`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects)

```
def test_password_reset_form(self):
    ...
    # A URL that redirects can be followed to termination.
    response = self.client.get(reverse('reset-password-confirm', args=[...]), follow=True)
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('dashboard-login'), status_code=302, target_status_code=200)
    self.assertEqual(len(response.redirect_chain), 2)
```

If your request used the *follow* argument, the **expected_url** and **target_status_code** will be the url and status code for the final point of the redirect chain.

> Reference:
>   https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/test_client/tests.py

Alternatively you can create two separate test cases (*when user is logged-in*, *when user is not logged-in*) and use **assertEqual**

```
# Test for logged in user.
def test_password_reset_form_for_logged_in_user(self):
   ...
   # do stuff
   self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

# Test if user not logged in.
def test_password_reset_form_if_user_not_logged_in(self):
   ...
   # do stuff
   self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem** (*Post Mortem*)**:**

Let's start with defining the problem:

- **Status 302:**

  > The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI. -[source](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)

  So that leads us to assume that you are getting redirected thus the test fails.
- **Where this happens:**

  In your `get()` method we find this code:

  ```
  if user is None:
      return redirect(reverse('dashboard-login'))
  ```

  So if the user is `Anonymous` (Unauthenticated) the view redirects him to the login page.

From the above, we can state that the problem occurs when you make an unauthenticated request to `PasswordResetConfirmView.get()`.

---

**Solution:**

You need to authenticate (login) your user before you make the request.
You can do this by utilizing the [`force_login()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login) method:

> If your site uses Django’s authentication system, you can use the `force_login()` method to simulate the effect of a user logging into the site. Use this method instead of `login()` when a test requires a user be logged in and the details of how a user logged in aren’t important.

```
def my_test_case():
    ... Do stuff ...
    # Login
    self.client.force_login(self.user)
    # Make the request
    response = self.client.get(...)
```